# Performance issue in SQL Server Analysis Services Multidimensional Data Model

Tags: sql-server, ssas

We have a star multidimensional model in SSAS in SQL Server 2019 with 4 fact tables and about 600 million records on each fact and many dimension tables with about 1.5 million records and there is no any relation between dimension tables, we have a challenge as the following :
after full process the MDX Queries take many time to respond at first call and after that it takes a little seconds to respond, I think the second call is from cache, but the first call is our main issue.

Please help us at this issue from different aspects, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at using Aggregations in your SSAS cubes? It has been many years since I worked with SSAS but I remember using them to speed up response time back in 2005 and 2008. You can start with the built in wizard and see if that helps. There was also a way to log user usage and build aggregations based on actual usage but there was a cost with that method. You can start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/designing-aggregations-analysis-services-multidimensional?view=asallproducts-allversions.

Comment: Thanks a lot from your suggestion, it's helped us really in general.

Comment: Hi, I have another issue, in MDX query, I select some measures as values and a row field from dim1, when I use a field from dim1 for filter, it works well, but when using another field from dim2 for example for filter, it takes too long to respond, please give some hints, thanks in advance for all kinds of you and also dba.stackexchange.

Comment: Sorry but I never used much mdx.